# How can I memcpy between *c_char and Vec<u8>

Tags: rust, ffi

I have a `Vec<u8>` which is pretending to be a large disk:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref DISK: Mutex<Vec<u8>> = Mutex::new(vec![0; 100 * 1024 * 1024]);
}
```

My Rust code (called from C directly) has some functions to read and write into this disk, but I don't understand what I'd write in those functions to memcpy between the disk and the C caller (or if `Vec` is the best structure to use here at all):

```
extern "C" fn pread(
    _h: *mut c_void,
    buf: *mut c_char,
    _count: uint32_t,
    offset: uint64_t,
    _flags: uint32_t,
) -> c_int {
    // ?
}

extern "C" fn pwrite(
    _h: *mut c_void,
    buf: *const c_char,
    _count: uint32_t,
    offset: uint64_t,
    _flags: uint32_t,
) -> c_int {
    // ?
}
```

Comment: Note `char` != `u8`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/fn.copy_nonoverlapping.html).

```
use std::ptr;

// Copy from disk to buffer
extern "C" unsafe fn pread(
    _h: *mut c_void,
    buf: *mut c_char,
    count: uint32_t,
    offset: uint64_t,
    _flags: uint32_t,
) -> c_int {
    // TODO: bounds check
    ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(&DISK.lock()[offset], buf as *mut u8, count);
    count
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `Cstring::from_raw(buf).into_bytes()` and vice versa ([documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.from_raw)) to convert `buf` to/from byte slice, then [copy_from_slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_from_slice) to copy data to `DISK` - this function uses memcpy internally